# wxPython: displaying multiple widgets in same frame

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to be able to display `Notebook` and a `TxtCtrl` wx widgets in a single frame.  Below is an example adapted from the wxpython wiki; is it possible to change their layout (maybe with something like `wx.SplitterWindow`) to display the text box below the `Notebook` in the same frame?

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sheet as sheet

class MySheet(sheet.CSheet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        sheet.CSheet.__init__(self, parent)

        self.SetLabelBackgroundColour('#CCFF66')
        self.SetNumberRows(50)
        self.SetNumberCols(50)


class Notebook(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 600))
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(101, 'Quit', '' )
        menubar.Append(file, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 101, self.OnQuit)
        nb = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.NB_BOTTOM)
        self.sheet1 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet2 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet3 = MySheet(nb)
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet1, "Sheet1")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet2, "Sheet2")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet3, "Sheet3")
        self.sheet1.SetFocus()
        self.StatusBar()

    def StatusBar(self):
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450, 400))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Center()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Notebook(None, -1, 'notebook.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        frame2 = MyFrame(None, -1, '')
        frame2.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame2)
        return True


app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making two widgets appear on the same frame is easy, actually. You should use sizers to accomplish this.

In your example, you can change your `Notebook` class implementation to something like this:

```
class Notebook(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 600))
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(101, 'Quit', '' )
        menubar.Append(file, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 101, self.OnQuit)
        nb = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.NB_BOTTOM)
        self.sheet1 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet2 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet3 = MySheet(nb)
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet1, "Sheet1")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet2, "Sheet2")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet3, "Sheet3")
        self.sheet1.SetFocus()
        self.StatusBar()
        # new code begins here:
        # add your text ctrl:
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        # create a new sizer for both controls:
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # add notebook first, with size factor 2:
        sizer.Add(nb, 2)
        # then text, size factor 1, maximized
        sizer.Add(self.text, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        # assign the sizer to Frame:
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
```

Only the `__init__` method is changed. Note that you can manipulate the proportions between the notebook and text control by changing the second argument of the `Add` method.

You can learn more about sizers from the official [Sizer overview](https://docs.wxpython.org/sizers_overview.html) article.

Comment: That link works, but you should replace it with https://docs.wxpython.org/sizers_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a splitter, yes.

Also, it makes sense to create a Panel, place your widgets in it (with sizers), and add this panel to the Frame.

Comment: Could you add a few tips on how I might do that, with reference to the above classes?