# How to use sizers in Wxpython to place multiple widgets in the same frame?

Tags: wxpython

Please Note : This is not a duplicate of [wxPython: displaying multiple widgets in same frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181573/wxpython-displaying-multiple-widgets-in-same-frame?rq=1) , its an added doubt to the question.

Ok so, I already have a Notebook and a Button on the same frame.
Source Code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sheet as sheet

class MySheet(sheet.CSheet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        sheet.CSheet.__init__(self, parent)

        self.SetLabelBackgroundColour('#CCFF66')
        self.SetNumberRows(50)
        self.SetNumberCols(50)


class Notebook(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 600))
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(101, 'Quit', '' )
        menubar.Append(file, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 101, self.OnQuit)
        nb = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.NB_BOTTOM)
        self.sheet1 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet2 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet3 = MySheet(nb)
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet1, "Sheet1")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet2, "Sheet2")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet3, "Sheet3")
        self.sheet1.SetFocus()
        self.StatusBar()



        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, label = "Ok")
        #self.button2 = wx.Button(self, -1, label = "Not Ok")

        sizerV = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # add notebook first, with size factor 2:
        sizerV.Add(nb, 5)
        # then text, size factor 1, maximized
        sizerV.Add(self.button1, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # assign the sizer to Frame:
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizerV)

def StatusBar(self):
    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()

def OnQuit(self, event):
    self.Close()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450, 400))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Center()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Notebook(None, -1, 'Pandel.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        frame2 = MyFrame(None, -1, '')
        self.SetTopWindow(frame2)
        return True


app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

OUTPUT : 
[image: sample output]

But I want two Buttons that are adjacent to each other, instead of that one big button across my screen.

That is I want to use wx.HORIZONTAL and WX.VERTICAL sizers together. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to think of sizers and panels and such is that they are containers. For complex layouts, I recommend grabbing a pencil and a piece of paper and sketching out your layout. Then draw boxes around the widgets. Those boxes are your sizers (or sometimes they are panels AND sizers). Anyway, you'll quickly realize from all that drawing that the boxes can be nested inside each other. That is the key with BoxSizers. You can nest them! It can get confusing, but if you keep your code really clear and well designed, it works great.

Anyway enough of my prose, here's the code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sheet as sheet

class MySheet(sheet.CSheet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        sheet.CSheet.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetLabelBackgroundColour('#CCFF66')
        self.SetNumberRows(50)
        self.SetNumberCols(50)

class Notebook(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 600))
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(101, 'Quit', '' )
        menubar.Append(file, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 101, self.OnQuit)
        nb = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.NB_BOTTOM)
        self.sheet1 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet2 = MySheet(nb)
        self.sheet3 = MySheet(nb)
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet1, "Sheet1")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet2, "Sheet2")
        nb.AddPage(self.sheet3, "Sheet3")
        self.sheet1.SetFocus()
        self.StatusBar()
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, label = "Ok")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self, -1, label = "Not Ok")
        sizerV = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizerH = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        # add notebook first, with size factor 2:
        sizerV.Add(nb, 5)
        # then text, size factor 1, maximized
        sizerH.Add(self.button1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizerH.Add(self.button2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizerV.Add(sizerH, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        # assign the sizer to Frame:
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizerV)

    def StatusBar(self):
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450, 400))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Center()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Notebook(None, -1, 'Pandel.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        frame2 = MyFrame(None, -1, '')
        self.SetTopWindow(frame2)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```